# Get GradCAM image for Mel-Spectrogram from CNN saved model in Python

Tags: python, keras, model

After extracting the MFCCs via this code:

```
def extract_features(file_name):
    try:
        audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name, res_type='kaiser_fast')
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=nmfcc)
        pad_width = max_pad_len - mfccs.shape[1]
        mfccs = np.pad(mfccs, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error encountered while parsing file: ", file_name)
        return None

    return mfccs
```

I pass the MFCCs through a shallow network (shown below) and then save the model:

```
# Construct model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```

This is the model summary:

[image]

I recall the model via:

```
def print_prediction(file_name):
    prediction_feature = extract_features(file_name)
    prediction_feature = prediction_feature.reshape(1, num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)
    model_path = os.path.join("ModelPath")
    model = load_model(filepath)

    predicted_vector = np.argmax(model.predict(prediction_feature), axis=-1)
    predicted_class = le.inverse_transform(predicted_vector)
    print('Filename: ', os.path.basename(file_name))
    print("The predicted class is:", predicted_class[0])

    predicted_proba_vector = model.predict(prediction_feature)
    predicted_proba = predicted_proba_vector[0]
    for i in range(len(predicted_proba)):
        category = le.inverse_transform(np.array([i]))
        print(category[0], "\t\t : ", format(predicted_proba[i], '.15f'))
    print('\n')

    return predicted_proba_vector
```

How can I go about getting a GradCAM image for my audio file that I pass into the CNN model?

Comment: Here is explanation of similar task https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/ you only have more classes than 2 i guess. Only difference is you will use your defined and trained model instead of pretrained models in these examples. Also i suggest you to take https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-computer-vision-with-tensorflow course. I  learn a lot, if you have time take full specialization..